# Android: Setting the Weight parameter programmatically does the opposite of what i want

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I'm having a problem with android.
I'm setting the Weight parameter in Java, but it's doing exactly the oposite of what I want.

Here's the code

```
LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(context);
// some code ...
container.setWeightSum(1f);

View v1 = new View(context);
v1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p1.weight=0.1f;

View v2 = new View(context);
v2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p2.weight=0.9f;

container.addView(v1,p1);
container.addView(v2,p2);
```

I repeat this process 7 times with adding a black line between the container layout.
Normally I should get a small red column on the lef, and a large black one, but here's what I get with this code :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPgoy.png]

Why does it doing exactly the opposite of the code ?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? mostly black with only a little red? If so just switch your weight values, you have the backward.

Comment: try with width 0 for with children

Comment: @DheereshSingh Great! it worked with width 0 for children. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When we use the weight width should be Zero

try with width 0 for with children inside the container.............

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



LinearLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting both widths to "wrap_content"... when using weights you should set the affected orientation to "0dp" (or it's programatic equivalent).

Comment: This was killing me too. But the odd thing is why is it the exact opposite when using WRAP_CONTENT?